# What are the literary devices that appear in these two quotes?

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

> Majestic and minute, remote and magically near, frank and divinely enigmatic.

It's a polysyndeton but since antonyms are used there would it be juxtaposition? I thought it wouldn't be oxymoron or paradox.

> Then I knew that the hopelessly poignant thing was not Lolita’s absence from my side, but the absence of her voice from that concord.

There could just be nothing here and I'm just overthinking it. Is there any literary device for negating a previous proposition/statement and giving another? If not, I suppose I can just say that the repetition of 'absence' is used, I guess?

Comment: _Paradox_ for the first. Not sure about the second. _Hyperbole_, perhaps.

Comment: (1) is certainly polysyndeton and if a person or life-force is being described here, three instances of oxymoron (see 'antonym pairs' at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron)). // I don't think (2) uses a _proportionality_. Perhaps it's the use of 'absence' twice _in slightly different ways_ (physical absence, lack of communicational input).